# IE11: security level edit bar not even visible

Tags: security, internet-explorer-11, internet-security

The security level bar is missing in IE11 (it's german, sorry for that):

[image]

I have read the documentation of some registry keys and modified them to test a few things. But I cannot make it appear. Especially the "flags" key for Zone 3 is set to 1, which should be fine. I have found a few people who complain about the bar being greyed out, but that's not my problem: the bar is not even visible.

Answer (score 0):

Google's translator tells me that "Benutzerdefiniert" means "Custom", which explains what you are seeing.

In Windows 10 with IE 11, what I see is that if the security level for the zone is set to "Custom", the slider is not shown.  This is because the slider just sets a configuration that pre-sets all of the granular settings underneath for the security level you choose.  With a Custom setting for the zone (which will occur if you change any of the default settings associated with that level) it will look something like this:

[image: No slider with Custom level]

So if you want to see the slider instead of customizing the configuration for that zone, just click first on the "Default level" button and the slider will re-appear.  (Once you've done that, the Default Level button will be greyed out.)

[image: Default level with no customization and slider showing]

If you don't want to accept one of MS's preconfigured levels, you can either leave it at Custom or start with one of the Default levels, and then tweak the granular configuration by clicking on "Custom level" and setting what details you want to change.  Either way, once you make a change, the slider will disappear and the level will show as "Custom" again.

[image: Sample of custom settings that can be tweaked for a zone]